# Orthogonal matrix norm

Tags: matrices, orthogonality

If $H$ is an orthogonal matrix, then $||H||=1$ and $||HA||=||A||, \forall A$-matrix (such that we can writ $H \cdot A$).

What norm is this about?

Comment: you know that $H$ is orthogonal also means that $\|Hx\|^2 =\|x\|^2$ for any vector $x$ (with $\|.\|$ the Euclidean norm, a norm induced by an inner product)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This holds for any norm induced by an inner product. This follows from
$$\|QA\|=\sqrt{(QA,QA)}=\sqrt{(Q^TQA,A)}=\sqrt{(A,A)} = \|A\|$$

With $Q$ an orthonormal matrix, i.e., $Q^{-1}=Q^T$.

Comment: (ok but there is also the operator norm on a Hilbert space which is not induced by an inner product)

Comment: Why is this the selected answer? It doesn't even make sense. If A and Q are matrices, what is `(A,A)`? At the very least, any correct answer needs to talk about an operator norm.

Comment: @Paul: here, $(A,A)$ is any inner product on the matrices. The most common one is $(A,B)=\text{Tr}(B^*A)$.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 28):

The operator norm
$$
\|A\|=\max\{\|Ax\|_2:\ \|x\|=1\},
$$
where $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the Euclidean norm, also satisfies those two equalities. They follow easily from the fact that $\|y\|_2^2=y^Ty$, so $$\|Hx\|_2^2=(Hx)^THx=x^TH^THx=x^Tx=\|x\|_2^2.$$

Comment: But this is a matrix-vector norm, not a matrix-matrix norm, as stated by the OP

Comment: A norm is a norm. And the operator norm satisfies $\|HA\|=\|A$ for every orthogonal $H$ and arbitrary $A$.

Comment: I see your point. I suppose it is a trivial step to say that H not changing the norm of any vector x means that it does not change the maximum norm over all vectors `Ax`, but perhaps not immediately obvious if you start by writing down the definition of `||HA||`.

Comment: What I mean is that I think the two different interpretations -- ||A|| as a matrix norm or ||A|| as a vector norm -- warrant two different proofs.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see the difference. What is "the operator noem as a matrix norm"?

Comment: Maybe I am overcomplicating things. I just mean the operator norm, applied to matrices in this case

Comment: Well, yes. If you look carefully, the computations in your answer are exactly those in mine, with the only difference that I limited it to real matrices.

Comment: I agree, the differences are purely formal, which means they *might* have different natural interpretations

Answer (score 14):

The frobenius norm, $||A||_F^2 = tr(A A^T)$ satisfies this property. You can see this by noting $|| H A||_F^2 = tr( HA (HA)^T) = tr(H A A^T H^T) = tr(H^T H A A^T) = tr( I A A^T ) = tr(A A^T) = ||A||_F^2$.

Comment: why is $tr(H A A^T H^T) = tr(H^T H A A^T)$?

Comment: Trace is invariant to cyclic permutations.

Answer (score 2):

The original question was asking about a matrix H and a matrix A, so presumably we are talking about the operator norm. The selected answer doesn't parse with the definitions of A and H stated by the OP -- if A is a matrix or more generally an operator, (A,A) is not defined (unless you have actually defined an inner product on the space of linear operators, but if that is the case it may be surprising to the OP)

The operator norm of AH would usually be defined by

$$||HA||=\sup_{||x||=1} ||HAx||$$
where $||.||$ is any norm, such as the norm induced by the inner product (the euclidean norm in the case of the dot-product) .
$$=\sup_{||x||=1} \sqrt{(HAx,HAx)}$$
$$=\sup_{||x||=1} \sqrt{(H^*HAx,Ax)} $$
(definition of adjoint)
$$=\sup_{||x||=1} \sqrt{(Ax,Ax)} $$
 (H is an orthogonal matrix)
$$=\sup_{||x||=1} ||Ax||$$
(definition of operator norm)
$$=||A||$$