# Prove that orthogonal matrix $Q$ preserves operator norm i.e. $||AQ||_2 = ||A||_2$

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754712/orthogonal-matrix-norm) proves that $||QA||_2 = ||A||_2$:

$||QA||_2 = \sup_{||x||=1}{||QAx||}=\sup_{||x||=1}{\sqrt{(QAx)^T(QAx)}} = 
\sup_{||x||=1}{\sqrt{x^TA^TQ^TQAx|}} = sup_{||x||=1}{\sqrt{x^TA^TAx}} = ||A||_2$

How to prove it for $||AQ||_2$ too?

Comment: You could use your approach together with $\|B^T\|_2 = \|B\|_2$

Comment: @StefanHante what if $Q$ is an orthogonal but not square matrix?

Comment: Orthogonal matrices are by definition square. But the proof in the question works for any rectangular matrix $Q$ such that $QA$ is well defined and that satisfies $Q^TQ=I$. You can still use $\|QA\|_2=\|(QA)^T\|_2=\|A^TQ^T\|_2$ to answer the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We denote $\langle x, y\rangle_2 = x^Ty$. Then you have 
$$ \Vert Qx \Vert_2 = \langle Qx, Qx\rangle_2 = \langle x, Q^TQx\rangle_2 = \langle x, x\rangle_2 = \Vert x \Vert_2.$$
Therefore we have $\{x \in \mathbb R^n : \Vert x \Vert_2 = 1\} = \{x \in \mathbb R^n : \Vert Qx \Vert_2 = 1\}$. Thus we get $\sup_{\Vert x \Vert_2 = 1}{\Vert AQx \Vert_2}= \sup_{\Vert Qx \Vert_2 = 1}{\Vert A Qx \Vert_2}$ for the suprema.

Hence you get 
$$\Vert AQ \Vert_2 = \sup_{\Vert x \Vert_2 = 1}{\Vert AQx \Vert_2}= \sup_{\Vert Qx \Vert_2 = 1}{\Vert A Qx \Vert_2} =  \sup_{\Vert y \Vert_2 = 1}{\Vert Ay \Vert_2} = \Vert A \Vert_2.$$

Comment: Could you explain why it's okay to substitute x with Qx? I understand they have the same norm but I don't see implication ||Qx||=||x|| => ||AQx||=||Ax||

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly to make it more clear :)

Answer (score 2):

The map $Q$ preserves the unit sphere, so the sup of $\|AQx\|$ over the unit sphere will be equal to the sup of $\|A\|$ over the unit sphere.