# For an orthogonal matrix $Q$, prove $\operatorname{cond}(Q)=1$

Tags: matrices, orthogonal-matrices, condition-number, spectral-norm

> Given an orthogonal matrix $Q$, prove $$\|Q\|_2\cdot \|Q^{-1}\|_2=1$$

I succeed to solve it with eigenvalues but I'm looking for an easier way.

Comment: An orthogonal matrix actually [has operator norm equal to $1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1754723/643882). And if $Q$ is orthogonal, then so is $Q^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An orthogonal matrix preserves distance (it's an *isometry*). It means that for any $\mathbf x$ we have $\|Q\mathbf x\|_2=\|\mathbf x\|_2$.

So:
$$\|Q\|_2 \overset{\text{def}}= \sup_{\mathbf x\ne \mathbf 0}\frac{\|Q\mathbf x\|_2}{\|\mathbf x\|_2} = \sup_{\mathbf x\ne \mathbf 0}\frac{\|\mathbf x\|_2}{\|\mathbf x\|_2}=1$$
Since $Q^{-1}$ is orthogonal as well, the result follows.