# Explanation for derivation using properties of rotation matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, computational-mathematics

In a paper I am reading, I found a result that I have been trying to work through but I am a bit stuck. The paper states that the expression for a transformation is:

$ f = M^{-1}(S*x - T)$

where f is the coordinates of a point in one coordinate system in R3, x is the coordinates in a different coordinate system in R3, S is a scaling matrix, T is a translation vector, and M is a rotation matrix. Then the author goes ahead and states that because the transpose of a rotation matrix is equal to its inverse, the following expression can be derived:

$ ||T - S*x||^2 = ||f||^2 $

I am not exactly sure how this expression was derived. I was hoping someone could provide some insight. I tried working through it using a dot product definition for the norm indicated, but I am not sure how that would help.

Comment: Here it is shown that the matrix norm of an orthogonal matrix ($M$ is orthogonal and thus $M^{-1}=M^T$ as well) is one : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754712/orthogonal-matrix-norm This should make the statement obvious

Comment: Yes, thank you! That was a very helpful link.

Answer (score 1):

This is coming from

$$\begin{aligned}
\Vert f \Vert^2 &= f^Tf = [M^{-1}(S*x - T)]^T [M^{-1}(S*x - T)]\\
&=(S*x - T)^T (M^{-1})^TM^{-1}(S*x - T)\\
&=(S*x - T)^T MM^{-1}(S*x - T)\\
&=(S*x - T)^T (S*x - T) = \Vert S*x-T \Vert^2
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thank you for the response! After reading your answer, I think that the sign of the vectors within the norm on the LHS does not matter. This was one of the main issues I was having when solving. I could not figure out why the signs were switched. Would my conclusion accurate?

Comment: @MathLoser For sure as for any vector $x$: $\Vert x \Vert = \Vert -x \Vert$.